# How to continue an interrupted mencoder converting process?

Tags: mencoder

I'm converting with this:

```
mencoder "$FILENAME" -o "$OUTPUTFILENAMEINPROG.avi" -ovc x264 -x264encopts bitrate=450 nr=2000 vcodec=mpeg4:mbd=2:mv0:trell:v4mv:cbp:last_pred=3:predia=2:dia=2:vmax_b_frames=2:vb_strategy=1:precmp=2:cmp=2:subcmp=2:preme=2:qns=2 -oac mp3lame -lameopts cbr:br=128 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

but if it get's interrupted, how can I continue where I was? converting again the full video to that point where it got corrupted takes too much time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are doing a 2 pass encoding you can't and even if you are you can only restart from the point where the 2nd pass starts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You will have to start over from the beginning, and keep your cats away from the power strip this time. :)